# How do I make VBA code cleaner and with less points?

Tags: excel, vba, code-cleanup

I'm opening a file to read your data, but I think the code is too big, would you have it smaller or cleaner?

```
Private Function HeaderValidation(workbook As Workbook, nameInstitution As String) As String
Dim mensage As String
Dim headersTranslator(5) As String
Dim headers(5) As String
Dim i As Integer

headers(0) = workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B5").value
headers(1) = workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").value
headers(2) = workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("F5").value
headers(3) = workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("E5").value
headers(3) = workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("G5").value

headersTranslator(0) = "Client (B5)"
headersTranslator(1) = "back (A2)"
headersTranslator(2) = "ATM (F5)"
headersTranslator(3) = "ValueInsert (E5)"
headersTranslator(3) = "DM (G5)"

For i = 0 To UBound(headersTranslator) - 1
    If Left(headersTranslator(i), Len(headersTranslator(i)) - 5) <> headers(i) Then
        mensage = mensage & headersTranslator(i)
        If i <> UBound(headersTranslator) - 1 Then
            mensage = mensage & ", "
        End If
    End If
Next i
HeaderValidation = mensage

End Function
```

I want to fix the `Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B5").Value`

Comment: So, the code is running, right?

Comment: `HeaderTranslator(3)` is listed twice.

Comment: `With workbook.Worksheets(1) ... End With`

Comment: `Dim headers(5)` create a zero-based array with upper bound 5, so you have an empty slot at `headers(5)`

Comment: `headers(3)` listed twice

Comment: thank you, I'll pack here @PGSystemTester

Comment: @Storax I wanted to leave access to the more descriptive value, such as Range("A1"). Instead of Workbook.Worksheets (1) .Range ("B5"). Value

Comment: Or possibly name the ranges as the header? So `client` = `range("client").value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
Private Function HeaderValidation(Workbook As Workbook) As String
    Dim mensage As String, arr, h

    For Each h In Array("Client|B5", "back|A2", "ATM|F5", _
                        "ValueInsert|E5", "DM|G5")
        arr = Split(h, "|")
        If arr(0) <> Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range(arr(1)).Value Then
            mensage = mensage & IIf(mensage <> "", vbLf, "") & _
                      arr(0) & " not found at " & arr(1)
        End If
    Next h
    HeaderValidation = mensage
End Function
```

It would be more flexible if you passed in a worksheet instead of a workbook: you could also pass in the header array as an argument and then the function can be reused across different sheet types.

Answer (score 1):

quite similar to Tim's solution, but with usage of `Dicionary` object

```
Private Function HeaderValidation(sht As Worksheet) As String
    Dim message As String, key As Variant

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .Add "B5", "Client"
        .Add "A2", "back"
        .Add "F5", "ATM"
        .Add "E5", "ValueInsert"
        .Add "G6", "DM"

        For Each key In .Keys
            If sht.Range(key).Value2 <> .Item(key) Then message = message & .Item(key) & " (" & key & ")" & vbNewLine
        Next
    End With
    HeaderValidation = message
End Function
```

as you can see I also:

- preferred to pass worksheet object instead of workbook of which using some sheet
- didn't use `nameInstitution` since it wasn't used in your code

As Tim has pointed out, it could be preferable to set the header-address pairs outside the Function which would accept it as a parameter, like follows:

```
Private Function HeaderValidation(sht As Worksheet, dict As Object) As String
    Dim message As String, key As Variant

    With dict
        For Each key In .Keys
            If sht.Range(key).Value2 <> .Item(key) Then message = message & .Item(key) & " (" & key & ")" & vbNewLine
        Next
    End With
    HeaderValidation = message
End Function
```

where your "main" code would have something like:

```
Sub main()

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With dict
        .Add "B5", "Client"
        .Add "A2", "back"
        .Add "F5", "ATM"
        .Add "E5", "ValueInsert"
        .Add "G6", "DM"
    End With

    (any code)    

    MsgBox HeaderValidation2(ActiveSheet, dict)

    (any code)

End Sub
```